# Using more than one form and staying on page with Ajax/php/jquery Syntax help required

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, syntax

Trying to process form and stay on same page. I aim to be able to click on buttons under photos to classify them. I will have 100 photos on every page so I'd rather just be able to click around rather than having a dedicated page for every photo.
Following a few threads on here I am nearly there. I just need a point in the right direction. My code works except it reads in all three forms and not just the one that I clicked on. Each form has a button that can set a category of 1,2 or 3. Regardless of which button I press it updates the category to 3. So it's leaking out of form and reading all forms and as the last one is 3 it updates the value to 3.

Any help greatly appreciated.

```
<!--(Header)-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "test_ajax_update_code.php",
        data: $("FORM").serialize(),
    });
});
</script>
<!--(Body)-->
<img src="GLJ9988.jpg" width="500" height="333" border="0"><br>
<form>
    <input name="num" type="hidden" value="9988" >
    <input name="shw" type="hidden" value="1" >
    <input type="submit" value="1">
</form>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<form>
    <input name="num" type="hidden" value="9988" >
    <input name="shw" type="hidden" value="2" >
    <input type="submit" value="2">
</form>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<form>
    <input name="num" type="hidden" value="9988" >
    <input name="shw" type="hidden" value="3" >
    <input type="submit" value="3">
</form>
```

Comment: You are serializing each and every form by selecting every form like this `$('FORM').serialize()` so it is getting key and values from each and every form and when you send these values to the `url` it uses last key `value =>  pair`. So for this you would need a unique Identifier `id` on you form or you can use `this` in your logic.

Comment: If I give every form an id how do I address them in the ajax code? 
I tried onSubmit="return myfunction(this)" on each form but was not sure where to put the function name in the script code so could not get it working.

Answer (score 0):

You did not need 3 forms...
1 is enough, just edit first form, replace second input(name=shw) with select box and add few lines of javascript(jQuery)

```
<form>
  <input name="num" value="9988">
  <button id="1">cat 1</button>
  <button id="2">cat 2</button>
  <button id="3">cat 3</button>
  <select name="shw" style="display:none;">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("form button").on("click",function(){
    var selected = $(this).attr("id");
    $("form").find("select").val(selected);  
    // ajax here
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I added the exact same ajax code there and of course left in the link to "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com" but nothing updated, what am I missing?
Also, will this work when I have 100 photos on each page, ie, will it know which one I am on and not code leak to the last one?

Comment: input value can by send through form as array for example <input name"num[9988]" value="1">, in this way it means that image id 9988 has set value to 1.... in other way u did not need input just select box <select name="shw[9988]">...</select> and other select for another image <select name="shw[9989]">...</select>, but u need to modify jquery.

Comment: It is still not working. I am very pleased for your answer but I am still missing something. I can not get it to update the database using these select boxes. Once it is working I can move on to the advanced thing of 100 photos and 100 arrays, but for now I am struggling with the above code. You say "ajax here"; I inserted it to no avail. Missing something?

Comment: Brilliant. That's more than I could have wished for. However :) ..... Up to now I have used radio buttons for this and then used a "save" at the bottom. Because of connection problems I decided to recode it and update each photo class immediately, so I need the "submit" function moved to each button. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

bind a click event to your submit buttons and fire the ajax based on the clicked button form

```
$('input[type=submit]').on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "test_ajax_update_code.php",
        data: $(this).parent().serialize(),
    });
})
```

`$(this).parent()` select the first elements outside `this` thats in this case is the form element

use `preventDefault` to prevent page refresh

Comment: Thanks, but how do I bind a click event to my submit buttons? Nothing updated this time?

Comment: in my code i use the click event.... you need to use my code inside $(document).ready({ code goes here });